# jQuery mobile and PHP define variable

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm really new with jQuery mobile but am loving working with it! I've come across a few problems regarding caching that I'm struggling with.

I have a php file with the following `define` in it:

```
define('HEADING_TITLE', 'Page 1');
```

That file is loaded on page 1 of the website. When I echo HEADING_TITLE, I see 'Page 1'.

Page 2 requires a different php file that overrides HEADING_TITLE as follows:

```
define('HEADING_TITLE', 'Page 2');
```

When I echo HEADING_TITLE, I still see 'Page 1'. I know the page 2 define is being processed because if I add the line `die(HEADING_TITLE);` immediately after the define, the script does indeed die but still shows me 'Page 1'!

How do I get jQuery mobile to allow me to overwrite the HEADING_TITLE variable? Or will I need to go about this another way? Creating different define variables like PAGE1_HEADING_TITLE and PAGE2_HEADING_TITLE is no problem, but if there's a better way I'd love to know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is **you can't override a define**, they are called constants for a reason. Long answer is, [you can in the runtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php), but it's hacky and a bad idea.

If you choose to over-ride a constant in the runtime, do it like so:

```
runkit_constant_redefine("HEADING_TITLE", 'Page 2');
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll do it the cleaner way then :)

Comment: No problem :-) Just pass a $title variable down or something. Constants are more for things like the company phone number that is displayed everywhere,  or such things